# print char in assembly, MASM

Tags: assembly, struct, masm, x86-16

I'm just learning the assembly language.

I want to do inheritance in assembler, but I have a problem with displaying.

> ```
> (18) error A2080 Field cannot be overridden
> (19) error A2080 ...
> (29) arning A4031: Operand types must match
> ```

```
    ;************************************************************************************************************************;
;PROG3.ASM -KLASY w Asemblerze
Sc   struc
numerIndeksu     dw         ?
StudentName      db     6 dup   (?)
Sc   ends

Tc   struc
     dw              ?
     db     6 dup    (?)
k    dw          ?
d    dw          ?
Tc   ends

.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
MSG1   DB  "KLASY: ",'$'
S Sc <1,'Tom'>
T Tc <1,"Max",4>  
.CODE
main:   

MOV   AX,@DATA
MOV   DS,AX
LEA DX,MSG1         ;print msg1
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

MOV DL, S.numerIndeksu
MOV AH, 02h
INT 21H

CMP AL,13          ;ascii for "ENTER" key
JE EXIT

EXIT:
    MOV AH,4CH 
    INT 21H
END
```

Comment: `MOV DL, S.numerIndeksu` is a problem. You define `S.numerIndeksu` as a DW but are accessing only 1 byte. Maybe you meant `MOV DX, S.numerIndeksu` ? Or change `S.numerIndeksu` to be a `db`

Comment: int 21h/ah=2 doesn't print numbers without you converting them to a string first.

Comment: Ok. I will try do it. Thank You.